# Although println() is a good way to print a string, can you find a way to print a string without println in Scala?

Tags: scala

I got this question from "Learning Scala" by Jason Swatz

Comment: should be migrated to something like codegolf?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scala.Predef.print(x: Any): Unit`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#print(x:Any):Unit) or [`scala.Predef.printf(text: String, xs: Any*): Unit`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#printf(text:String,xs:Any*):Unit) instead, for example. You can also use Scala's host platform integration to call the host platform's native console output routines, e.g. [`System.out.println`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) on Scala-JVM, `console.log` on Scala.js, etc. You can use Scala's external process management to start a shell and call an external program to print output to the console (e.g. POSIX `echo`, POSIX `printf`, `ruby -e 'puts "Hello"'`, etc.) On Scala-JVM, you can use JNI to call the operating system's console output routines. You can use a custom assertion and violate it or a custom exception message and `throw` it, thus triggering a backtrace with your custom message to be printed.